# Can the namespace statement be "included" in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces, php-include

I have a file which looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace n;
f(); // this calls n\f()
```

PHP statements can be included by using the [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function, however, this doesn't work for the [`namespace`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) statement:

```
<?php
include('example_include_namespace_statement.php')
f(); // this doesn't call n\f()
```

example_include_namespace_statement.php:

```
<?php
namespace n;
```

Is there any way to "include" the namespace statement in PHP?

Or is it simply not possible?

Comment: No. The namespace covers only the file it's declared in

Comment: @Phil, You may wanna post that as answer since it's been 2 days and it doesn't seem that anyone else has a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the namespace when calling a function that is in a namespace, like so:

```
// test.php
namespace test;
function doesItWork() {
    return 'It Works!';
}
// index.php
include 'test.php';
echo test\doesItWork();
```

If you want to use a function that is defined in a namespace that is outside the current namespace then you must prefix it with the namespace character, like so:

```
echo \test\doesItWork();
```

You should read the [documentation on namespaces](http://php.net/namespaces).

Comment: I've read the documentation on namespaces. Having to precede the call with `\namespace\` means that the namespace statement is not "included" as what we would expect of from the includes of other statements. Is there any way to "include" the namespace statement in PHP?

Comment: @Pacerier Oh, are you thinking about auto-loading? - including the namespace whenever it is used, instead of having to include it manually?

Comment: No I'm thinking of `include`. The kind of `include` **behavior** we get when we `include` statements like `f();` etc. Auto-loading is auto-loading, not including......

Comment: Ah. Namespaced things have to be qualified (the full path has to be used). There is no way of "unpacking" the namespace so that you can use whatever is in it without qualifying it -- that would render namespaces pointless... You can alias namespaces, though, `use path\to\myNamespace;`, and then use it, `myNamespace\doesItWork()`. This makes longer namespaces easier to work with.